# Unable to get GoogleAuthToken on Signed apk

Tags: android, google-authentication

I am using following token to get Google Token using silent-signin method. I works fine with debug apk, but it never works for signed apk. Why ?

```
public String getGoogleToken() {
        String idToken = null;
        String SERVER_CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        String magicString = "audience:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID;
        try {
            idToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, Util.getUserEmail(this), magicString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return idToken;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating debug certificate fingerprint from keytool and signing with this certificate on google console than this type of problem occurs.because if you signed your apk than you must need To get the release certificate fingerprint.

So, Please read the instruction on [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)